# Updating/upgrading the perl module Sys::Hostname

Tags: updates, perl, dependencies

I want to run a piece of code that requires version 1.21 of Sys::Hostname.
My perl-5.28.1, installed using perlbrew at the time, came with version 1.20 of Sys::Hostname. I have searched online, but am unable to find how to install/upgrade to version 1.21. Can anyone help me out?

*edit: when I try to run:

```
cpanm Sys::Hostname
```

I get

```
skipping S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.28.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: That's quite strange, since Perl 5.28.1 should come with version 1.22 of `Sys::Hostname`, 1.20 would correspond with Perl 5.22.0 through 5.26.2. If you have multiple versions of Perl installed, are you sure you're running your script with the right one? For example, if your shebang is `#!/usr/bin/perl`, you might be running the script with your system Perl.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment! I must mention that I am relatively inexperienced with unix-based systems in general, so I apologise in advance for any stupidity on my part. After installing, I used `perlbrew switch perl-5.28.1` . A run of  `perl -v` confirms that perl 5.28.1 is the currently used version.

Comment: Ok, how do you run the Perl script? Is it `./script.pl`, or `perl script.pl`? Or are you maybe using `cron` to run the script? Also, what does the first line of the script look like (the "[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))" line), is it `#!/usr/bin/perl`, or maybe `#!/usr/bin/env perl`?

Comment: I run with `./script.pl`. The shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/env perl`. Sorry it took me a while to respond, I was away from the pc that has the files on it.

Comment: Ok, when you run `./script.pl`, it'll use the `perl` in the shebang line, since that's `/usr/bin/env perl`, `env` should use whichever `perl` comes first in the `PATH` - in other words, it should be the same `perl` as when you type just `perl` on the command line. On the same command line as you run `./script.pl`, what does `perl -MSys::Hostname -le 'print "$] $Sys::Hostname::VERSION"'` output? It *should* output `5.028001 1.22`. If not, please edit your question and add the full output of `perl -V` (that's a captial letter `-V`, not lowercase).